# Resizing fixed menu in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, resize

I addded the following jQuery code to make resizing for fixed menu in scroll case, but it doesn't work in ie8

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).on("scroll",function(){
        if(jQuery(document).scrollTop()>100){
            jQuery(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("small");
        } else{
            jQuery(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("small");
        }
    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Any more details? Any errors? Does it work if you wrap a document ready around the block?

Comment: Is this called after the element have been created? Otherwise you need to use `$(document).ready(function(){ /*yourCodeHere*/ });`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `window` instead of `document`, apparently IE <=8 ties the scroll event to it:

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll",function(){
    if(jQuery(document).scrollTop()>100){
        jQuery(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("small");
    } else{
        jQuery(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("small");
    }
});
```

---

### Compatibility table:

<sup>You can read more about this at [quirksmode.org DOM Events scroll and mousewheel](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html).</sup>

[image]